# I want to run a python script that logs me into a website. So when i go to the website using the browser i would already be logged in

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, cookies, authentication

Steps:

1. Go to website in google chrome not logged in.
2. Run python script
3. Go to website in google chrome now i'm logged in.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url="http://puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=211&signin=1"
    User="xxxxx"
    Pass="xxxxx"
    c.get(url)
    payload= {'username': User,
             'password': Pass,
             'submit':'Sign In',
             'signinoption':'1'}
    test = c.post(url,data=payload)
```

This script allows me to parse the website as logged in, but when I go to the website through chrome I'm not logged in. I assuming I need to somehow use the cookie to stay logged in.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Having a script that can automatically login me into a website sounds pretty cool. i also want to learn more about websites and how logins work.

Comment: sounds interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) if you haven't already. It is good practice to look things up in documentation to solve problems yourself. I believe this code I quickly typed up works. If not, hopefully it gives you a good idea of what you need to do.

```
import requests
url="http://puzzledragonx.com/en/monster.asp?n=211&signin=1"
User="xxxxx"
Pass="xxxxx"
payload = {'username': User,
           'password': Pass,
           }
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I want my script to log me in when i enter the site on the browser.